# structuring an interactive d3 force layout in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to build a site using angular and d3, without being particularly adept with either of them. I want to have a force layout that has a lot of functionality, so that I can select nodes and have them populate a sidebar with information, and then have options in that sidebar to update that node/find its neighbors/etc...

What I have is a mess and I keep running into problems trying to access the d3 module from various parts of the angular app, and vice versa. I currently have the d3 code within a directive, but this makes it difficult to call from the sidebar controller. Previously I had it in a service, but this made it difficult for d3 to access the force layout controller scope. (which I wanted to use to call `scope.$apply()`)

The following pieces need to work together:

- d3 (with event listeners on different svg objects)
- force layout element controller
- sidebar controller
- data service

Where do I put things (what kind of modules should I use, and what should I call from where?) so that I can always get at the d3 `.init()` function to add data, but d3 also plays nice with my fumbling attempt at developing around MVC principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is based off my experience developing an Angular/D3 App; you can look at the source code at it's [github repo](http://www.github.com/peterbsmith2/pillars).

The first principle of making a D3 directive in angular is that the controller will load the data and place the data on the directive using an attribute. That directive declaration might look something like:

```
<force-layout-chart data="force.data"></force-layout-chart>
```

Then in a controller like SideBarCtrl you pass data to

```
$scope.force = {
  data: response
};
```

The `response` would be coming from your data service...something like $http perhaps:

```
$http.get('/api/v2/foo/bar').then(function(response){
  $scope.force = {
    data: response
  };
})
```

Then within your `directive` you're using `scope.$watch` to listen for changes to `force.data`:

```
scope.$watch('data',function(response){
  if (!response) return;

  //Update your D3 here
});
```

The `response` object will be the data from `force.data`. In the directive `return` you'll want to enable two way data binding on the data attribute:

```
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {data: '='},  //two-way binding
   link: link
 }
```

The angular docs describe what the various methods of data binding are and why you might use them, but you'll almost definitely want `=` here.

Since you want to use multiple controllers to control this directive you should use the `require` property. [Explained briefly here.](https://coderwall.com/p/8teqba/angularjs-including-multiple-controllers-in-a-directive)

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {data: '='},
  require: ['SideBarCtrl','ForceCtrl'],
  link: link
};
```